# Wordpress: Show the parent menu title

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, title

I want to show the parent menu item above the submenu but when there is no submenu the parent menu item must not be showing then.

Now i use this code (page.php):

```
<div class="left">      
    <h2>
        <?php
            $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
            echo $parent_title;
        ?>
    </h2>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'Hoofdmenu','theme_location' => 'Hoofdmenu','sub_menu' => true) ); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

Output:

```
TITLE PARENT MENU
Subitem
Subitem
Subitem
------------
Widgets and stuff not important.
```

But with this code the parent menu item (title) is always visible even when there is no submenu...

Comment: Sorry, but I think you are going to have to provide some more context, show us which file you are running this code in and be clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Wezly, i have add some more code and i am telling what page it is. (page.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like what you need is a combination of checking if the page is a parent or not and then also seeing if it has children.

Something like this should work.

```
<?php

if ( is_page($post->ID) && $post->post_parent ) {
  $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent);
} else {
  $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
}

?>

<?php if($children):?>
  <h2>
    <?php 
    $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    echo $parent_title;
    ?>
  </h2>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: that is what I was trying to achieve for an answer, but unsuccessful so far. But looking at it, it seems like it should work.

Comment: I have test it and the title is not showing at all. With and without submenu.

Comment: I have edited the answer with another option that checks to see if the parent has children. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This is not helping. Now the whole parent menu is placed with the submenu's.

Comment: Try `get_pages` instead - I have edited the answer again - otherwise you may need to improve your question, give us some more context as to where this is being run.

Comment: Oke, now the parent title is showing again but still on every page with or without submenu.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a function from a similar question to get the parent menu title:

[Getting the current menu item id from specific menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232600/getting-the-current-menu-item-id-from-specific-menu)

```
function wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items )
{
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
            $GLOBALS['current_menu_title']=$menu_item->title;
            $GLOBALS['current_menu_ID'] =$menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            break;
        }
    }
    
        foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->ID==$GLOBALS['current_menu_ID'] ) {
            $GLOBALS['parent_menu_title'] =$menu_item->title;;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
```

Just use the variable `$GLOBALS['current_menu_title']`